# Is it possible to create a column in MySQL with an expression as a default value?

Tags: mysql, sql

How would one implement this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
  employeemonthly DECIMAL(10,2), 
  employeeyearly DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT employeemonthly*12
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use a insert trigger for that. Something like this

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER default_yearly BEFORE INSERT ON employee
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   
    SET NEW.employeeyearly = NEW.employeemonthly * 12;
  END;
|

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Trying it now

Comment: @NagHammadi: I updated my answer another time. I verified it and it works.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html):

```
CREATE VIEW vemployees AS
  SELECT e.employeemonthly,
         e.employeemonthly * 12 AS employeeyearly
    FROM EMPLOYEE e
```

...because there's little need to dedicate storage space for an easily calculated value.  Otherwise, use a function or simply write the expression into whatever query/stored procedure you need.

What really depends is:

- How often you need to access this data
- How complex the operation is to get the result you need

I recommend starting with not storing the value.  If performance gets to be a problem, then dedicate a column for the values storage -- not before.  At that, a trigger is a bit overkill to me, when you can use (psuedocode):

```
INSERT INTO employee 
  (...employeemonthly, employeeyearly, ...)
VALUES
  (...@employeemonthly, @employeemonthly * 12, ...
```

Comment: If I "dedicate a column for the values storage", do use juergen d's method?

Comment: @NagHammadi: Yes, a trigger is a good way to make sure the logic is applied to all interacting with the table.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [trigger for the insert event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), access the new record data using NEW and set the appropiate values.